# Enterprise portal: Set Page title at run time?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, enterprise-portal

I need to set page title for EP page that is created in VS using dataset created in AOT.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the page title on run time by adding the below code in the page load event

ITitleProvider titleProvider = AxBaseWebPart.GetWebpart(this) as ITitleProvider;

titleProvider.Caption = "Your title";